# Preview Excel in c# program and dynamically edit it

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, excel-2010

I have one question that I can't seem to understand even looking trough similar posts.

I have an Excel file that I use as a Template, I read it in the c# program and I fill it with data I want in the places I want and later it save it with other name.

But I would like to have a type of window in the program that can preview the template with the inserted data before creating it, like this the user wouldn't need to create the file if he only wanted to look to the data on it.

Is there a way to do this? Preferably recent one.

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Microsoft Excel 2010.

Thanks

Comment: [This might be a similar question][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386701/previewing-documents-word-excel-pdf-text-file-etc-within-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't get answered the main point that is the editing the preview file.
I read about the web browser control to show the excel but nothing about editing it :/

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a similar thing on my website, only on my website the rows are placed in the database and the user, that is admin can edit it in the database, so when I download the excel file again it will be populated by new values from the database.

Comment: But what about the preview itself?
My program steps would be:
1 - Query data from sql and cross it with few parameters, than I get some results.
2 - Preview the Empty Template.
3 - Input the step 1 data in the C# Preview of the Excel Template.
PS( In this step I don't want the user to edit it, I want the program itself to edit it according to the step 1 data)
4 - Export if wanted (this doesn't need to have connection to the preview file because I already have the code to create the file from the template and data from step1.

Am I explaining myself or I'm making it more confusing for you guys?

Comment: Yes you are, and I don't see anything wrong with your logic. You should read upon displaying excel files in c#, after you learn that it will be easy to populate the rows from the database. You can write a function with the same query that will create a document for the user to download or have a download embedded with the excel file display .
This might help:
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084#top